# postgresql trigger error control reached end of trigger without RETURN

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

**Edit: I have added the updated code to my post, I was missing a** `return null` **outside my IF block**

I have a table `working` with the most recent data and would like to add a trigger for updates made to it so that I can record the changes made to a particular column in another table `history`. I run this code to create a trigger function and test it but get an error

```
SQL Error [2F005]: ERROR: control reached end of trigger procedure without RETURN
  Where: PL/pgSQL function update_history()
```

My code:

```
-- create function for updates to track history
CREATE function update_history ()
RETURNS TRIGGER
as $$
BEGIN   
    IF NEW.discipline <> OLD.discipline THEN
    INSERT INTO history
        (ShiftId, fieldName, OldValue, NewValue)
    VALUES(New.shift_id, 'discipline', OLD.discipline, NEW.discipline);
    END IF;
return null; -- notice return outside the IF block
END;
$$
language plpgsql;


-- create trigger for my table after updates are made to the working table
create trigger update_history_trigger
after update on working
for each row execute PROCEDURE update_history();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function cannot reach the `RETURN` statement when the condition is not met. Place the statement outside the `IF` block. The returned value is ignored and you can use `NULL` instead of `NEW`.

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_history ()
RETURNS TRIGGER
AS $$
BEGIN
    IF NEW.discipline <> OLD.discipline THEN
        INSERT INTO history (ShiftId, fieldName, OldValue, NewValue)
        VALUES(NEW.shift_id, 'discipline', OLD.discipline, NEW.discipline);
    END IF;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Per [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html)

> The return value of a row-level trigger fired AFTER or a statement-level trigger fired BEFORE or AFTER is always ignored; it might as well be null.

Comment: Thanks! this worked great I've updated my post with the full solution